# Spring security OAuth2 client - Using refresh token without a prior Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm implementing a biometric authentication process which has complex steps and among these steps I have to use a refresh token stored in a database table and create a new AuthorizedClient.

So far, refreshing tokens when the user is already logged in is simple through the `AuthorizedClientManager`. This is well documented and nothing challenging about it.

The code looks like this (I'm using the Spring web flux and Reactive spring security but it's almost the same):

```
private Mono<OAuth2AuthorizedClient> authorizedClient(OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth2Authentication) {
        String clientRegistrationId = oauth2Authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest request = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId)
                .principal(oauth2Authentication).build();
        if (clientManager == null) {
            return Mono.error(new IllegalStateException(
                    "No ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager bean was found. Did you include the "
                            + "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client dependency?"));
        }
        return clientManager.authorize(request);
    }
```

However, when the user has no prior access token or authentication nor an existing session, the token can't be refreshed. At least I couldn't figure out how to.

I read most of spring security's oauth2 client code and can't figure out how to perform such thing.

I managed also to do that by hand I created a new WebClient and refreshed the token successfully.

However, to create manually the `Authentication` which is an instance of `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken` it's not straight forward and requires many params such as a valid `OAuth2AuthorizationExchange`.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: I've done this by imitating what's being done on a normal authentication. Still not optimal because the AuthorizationExchange.request should contain valid information not a "fake" strings.